# Lambic blend affecting beer in fridge?

Tags: off-flavor, storage, lambics

I have a Wyeast smack pack of Lambic blend in my fridge that I bought a month ago before I understood the complexity of brewing a Lambic. I had it next to some beers that I have really enjoyed previously (L'infusée by Brasserie du Monde, and an Imperial pale ale homebrew) and when I opened them both were not as good as they had been. I'm wondering whether having the Lambic pack in with them for a long period could have affected the flavours.

Comment: Do you mean an *unopened* yeast-pack spoiled some *unopened* beers?

Answer (score 3):

**Doubtful**

It is remotely possible for yeast packs to have microbes on the outside of packaging from contamination at packing time.  I don't see it contaminating unopened beers though.

Most likely the beer has just aged and changed in flavor as all beers do.

Answer (score 0):

Beers do not easily get infected from the outside. The only times I can confirm infection from the outside is corked beers where the cork shrunk due to old age.

Imperial Pale Ale sounds like a hoppy beer. Chances are the hops just fell out due to age. I think the flavours of the other beer also dropped out due to age.

Answer (score 0):

Hoppier beers should be enjoyed within a short time after brewing.  The hop will not age well after conditioning and lose flavor/body over time.  More than likely, you are simply tasting old beer.  Im not really familiar with the other Canadian beer, but I know it to be a herb/spiced beer, so one could conclude that the herbs/spices would change over time.  I know my pumpkin and holiday beers, which are spiced, change after a few months if there is left over from the holidays.

As stated above, no idea how a sealed yeast could effect an unopened beer bottle.  Mad science happening if so.